# Error 400 Bad request when getting Open Weather API (geolocation)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I want to get the weather API to display the current location but it gives back an 400 error. I don't know how to fix it. 
(I open my api on browser and its works fine. But when I put it in the code bellow, it's gave error)

```
state: {
        weather:{},
        api_key: 'c9f562aaffcdefaf40f2ed808d202c9b',
        url_base: 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/',
        query: '',
        icons: {
            'Rain': require('../assets/regnerisch.png'),
            'Clear': require('../assets/sonne.png'),
            'Clouds': require('../assets/wolkig.png'),
            'Snow': require('../assets/schnee.png'),
            'Drizzle':require('../assets/regnerisch.png'),
            'Thunderstorm':require('../assets/regnerisch.png')
        },          
    },

 actions:{
         currentCity({commit}) {
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
                axios
                .get(`${this.url_base}weather?&lat=${position.coords.latitude}&lon=${position.coords.longitude}&units=metric&APPID=${this.api_key}`)
                .then(res=>res.data)
                .then(weather=>{
                    commit('currentCity',weather)
                })            
            })
        }
    }
},
     mutations:{
         currentCity (state, weather){
             state.weather = weather
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using undefined variables inside axios call that is why its giving 400 bad request because of wrong url.
Working code in GitHub repo after cleaning up home and temperature components.  https://github.com/manojkmishra/weather_app_vuex_test
demo- https://weather-app-vuex-test.netlify.app/

Modify store.js as below

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import axios from 'axios';

Vue.use(Vuex);
export default new Vuex.Store({
state: { weather:{},    },
 actions:{
    async currentCity ({commit}, position)
    {   let url_base= 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/';
        let api_key= 'c9f562aaffcdefaf40f2ed808d202c9b';
        console.log('store-pos',position,url_base,api_key)
        let res=await axios.get(`${url_base}weather?&lat=${position.coords.latitude}&
        lon=${position.coords.longitude}&units=metric&APPID=${api_key}`)
            commit('CUR_CITY',res.data)
        return res;
    },

 },
 mutations:{
     CUR_CITY (state, weather)
     {   console.log('store-muta-state=',state)
         state.weather = weather

     }
 },
  getters:{}
})
```

modify home.js as below, cleanup your home.vue to test for only one component for eg-temperature and remove all others to check if everything is working.

```
import 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels';
import Temperature from '../temperature/Temperature.vue';
import { mapState} from 'vuex';
import '../../custom.scss';

export default {
computed: 
{  ...mapState({ weather: state => state.weather, 
                }),
},
components: {Temperature},
mounted() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => 
    {
        this.$store.dispatch('currentCity', position)
    });
},
};
```

Comment: the console.log returns data but the URL is still wrong, I guess. It's said that "coords" can't be defined and gives 400 errors

Comment: That error is from another request in different part of your code. Working code in GitHub repo after cleaning up home and temperature components (other components can be modified in similar way) https://github.com/manojkmishra/weather_app_vuex_test    demo-https://weather-app-vuex-test.netlify.app/     Please let me know if you are still facing 400 error

Comment: Hi @Manoj, I've tried to store  other method functions too but the url still wrong. For example with the "fetchWeather" function, where I have to search for a location through the input field, I've added the "query:''" object to the state and linked it in the url but it didn't work. Can you help me with that?

Comment: **Home.vue**: <input
          class="input"
          v-model="query"
          v-on:keyup.enter="fetchWeather(), fetchWeatherForecast(), getData()"
        />

Comment: **Home.js** : `computed: 
 {  ...mapState({ weather: state => state.weather})
 },
 components: {Temperature, Diagramm},
 mounted() {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => 
  {
   this.$store.dispatch('currentCity', position)
  });
   fetchWeather((query)=>{
   this.$store.dispatch('fetchWeather')
   })   
 }`

Comment: **store.js**:  `state: { weather:{},query:'' },
  actions:{
  
  async fetchWeather ({commit}){
   let url_base= 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/';
   let api_key= 'c9f562aaffcdefaf40f2ed808d202c9b';
   console.log('store-fetch', query,url_base, api_key)
   let res=await axios.get(`${url_base}weather?q=${state.query}&units=metric&APPID=${api_key}`)
   commit('FETCH_WEATHER', res.data)
   return res;
  }
  },

Comment: ` mutations:{
   CUR_CITY (state, weather)
   {  console.log('store-muta-state=',state)
    state.weather = weather
    
   },
  FETCH_WEATHER( state, weather)
  {state.weather = weather}
  },`

Answer (score 0):

400 error means your request was malformed. Since all of your payload data is storedas a query string I assume your url is wrong, Is this part below meant to be backticked?
`${this.url_base}weather?&lat=${position.coords.latitude}&lon=${position.coords.longitude}&units=metric&APPID=${this.api_key}`? Is yes then consider logging the variables to make sure you're getting valid input to the query string